# Is it possible to use hibernate where database does not support column aliases?

Tags: hibernate

If I am using database which does not support column-alias , How can I user hibernate with those databases?

Comment: Can you name a database that does not support column aliases? I really need to know one..

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be **NO**... I think it is ***not completely possible*** to use hibernate with database that does not support column aliases( though I haven't heard of any database that does not support column aliases..)

I am using ***not completely possible*** because hibernate has HQL where you can write queries with no column aliases. But it is not the only thing hibernate is used for.. :)

Column aliases define the ability of database to reduce the amount of code required for a query, and to make queries generally simpler to understand. In addition, aliasing can be used as an obfuscation technique to protect the real names of database fields.

And it is this feature of database that hibernate uses extensively to generate SQL queries. Here is a sample hibernate Generated SQL query

```
[DEBUG] 16:30:32,302 AbstractHibernateDAO - getSession :: Session opened successfully.
Hibernate: select tenant0_.ID as ID30_, tenant0_.NAME as NAME30_, tenant0_.SHORT_NAME as SHORT3_30_, tenant0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT4_30_, tenant0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS30_, tenant0_.REMARK as REMARK30_, tenant0_.ROOT as ROOT30_ from TENANT tenant0_ where tenant0_.ROOT='N' order by tenant0_.NAME
```

If I would know of a database that does not support column aliases.. I would surely like to  test to see the results.. But for now the answer would be **NO** based on complete hibernate utilization!!